# The simulator runtime in not available

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, upgrade

**Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib. Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.**

Occurs on **Xcode 7.1** when selecting, *ironically*, the **iOS 7.1 simulator**. This iOS 7 simulators are not available in Xcode 7, yet they still show up in the active scheme Device List. *See iPad2 (7.1), iPad Air (7.1), iPad Retina (7.1), iPhone 4s (7.1), etc. in the picture below:*

[image: Too many simulators]

How can I get rid of the unavailable simulators, short of re-installing Xcode? Besides, I just upgraded Xcode, which caused this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug that the 7.1 simulator is showing up in Xcode 7.  The iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime is not supported in Xcode 7.

If you want to remove those devices from the list, you can do so from Xcode's Devices Window.  You can find it in the Window Menu or get to it from shift-cmd-2.

You can also delete them from the command line using `xcrun simctl delete <UDID>`

If you have a new enough version of Xcode installed, you can also run 'xcrun simctl delete unavailable' to delete all unavailable devices.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`, since it does not require me knowing which simulators are valid, which ones are not, nor got through a list?